# How do I add a Microsoft account user to Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-8, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I am managing a small network with a Windows Server 2012 domain controller.  I have usernames of the network users who can access various network drives/files.

In the past, I would open up **Active Directory Users and Computers** and click **Users** > **New** > **User** to create a user account object which they user to log in.  But Microsoft has this new "Microsoft account" concept for Windows 8 users.  Their usernames are formatted like `john.smith@outlook.com` or `john.smith@live.com`.

But on my server, I cannot  change the domain name part of the user's logon name. It is stuck at `@MYCOMPANY.local`.  So how am I supposed to add these Microsoft account users so they, too, can access network drives?

Comment: Windows 8 users who have their own Microsoft accounts can join their Microsoft account with an AD account if the machine is joined to your domain. They can then sync files and settings...or are you after a corporate, automated method?

Answer (score 3):

You still create User accounts the same as you would for any other domain connected PC.

Once the AD account has been created, then the user is about to link their Microsoft account (john.smith@outlook.com) with their AD account (DOMAIN\johnsmith).

[Connect your Microsoft Account to your Domain Account.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/connect-microsoft-domain-account)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers might be a bit dated now.  I think there is an easier way now.  You can convert your microsoft account to a local account.  Windows 10 will automatically associate your microsoft account with the "new" local one it creates.

Log on to the user computer with the microsoft account.  Get into user account settings> your account and click the "sign in with local account instead" link. It will ask for the password and come up with a concerning message about how it will modify the account.